# Are there non-trivial graphs that uniquely embed to hypercubes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, embeddings, hypercube

The $n$-dimensional hypercube is the graph formed by $0$-$1$ sequences of length $n$ where two vertices are adjacent if they differ at only one place.
The weight of a sequence is the number of $1$'s in it.
For a (connected) subgraph of a hypercube we say that its *level-vector* is $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ if the number of its vertices with minimum weight is $n_1$, with minimum $+1$ weight is $n_2$ etc.
In other words, $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ is the number of vertices on the non-empty (adjacent) levels of the hypercube.

We say that a graph $G$ *level-uniquely embeds to hypercubes* if the level-vector of every induced subgraph of any hypercube that is isomorphic to $G$ is the same (and there is at least one hypercube that contains an induced subgraph that is isomorphic to $G$).

> > Is there a graph that level-uniquely embeds to hypercubes but is not a hypercube itself?

**Update 2014.12.28** This has been answered in the negative by Flo, see his answer below.

In fact, for my problem a slightly weaker condition would also suffice. Namely, I am also interested in graphs for which there is an $\alpha\ne -1$ such that for the level-vector $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ of every induced subgraph of any hypercube that is isomorphic to the graph it holds that $\alpha$ is the root of the *level-polynomial* $\sum n_ix^i$.

> > Is there a graph and an $\alpha\ne -1$ such that $\alpha$ is the root of every level-polynomial?

My motivation is that if there existed such a graph on a power of $2$ vertices, then I think it would give an example to the question posed [here](http://www.iwoca.org/problems/Griggs2014.pdf) using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/51822/955) method.
I've found some nice induced subhypercubes [here](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/JACO/Volume2_1/k312688v37355582.fulltext.pdf), but they were too big for me to verify anything.

---

***The text below is an exposition of the question by Wlodzimierz, edited by me***

Let $\ \mathbb B:=\{0\ 1\}.\ $ Let $\ \mathbb B^n\ $ be the $n$-cube. The elements of the $n$-cube are called vertices. The weight $\ \sum x\ $ of a vertex $\ x:=(x_1\ldots x_n)\in\mathbb B^n\ $ is defined as the sum of the coordinates, $\ \sum x := \sum_{k=1}^n x_k.\ $ Given an arbitrary set $\ A\subseteq\mathbb B^n,\ $ define the weigram $\ w_A:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z,\ $ where $\ w_A(k)\ $ is the number of vertices $\ x\in A\ $ of weight $\ k,\ $ for every $\ k=0\ldots n;\ $ also $\ w_A(k):=0\ $ whenever $\ k<0\ $ or $\ k>n.\ $

Consider arbitrary $\ A\ \subseteq \mathbb B^n, \ B\ \subseteq \mathbb B^m. $ We say that $\ B\ $ is a weight-shift of $\ A\ $ $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \exists_{d\in\mathbb Z}\forall_{k\in\mathbb Z}\ w_B(k) = w_A(k+d)$.

Now let's introduce the graph structure in the $n$-cube. Its edges are pairs $\ \{a\ b\}\subseteq\mathbb B^n\ $ such that $\ a\ b\ $ have exactly one coordinate different (i.e. $\ \sum |a-b| = 1$). Every $\ A\subseteq\mathbb B^n\ $ is considered to be a graph induced by the $n$-cube graph. Two subsets of the $n$-cube are considered to be isomorphic $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ they are isomorphic as graphs.

> **QUESTIONS** (consider implicitly the versions for connected graphs too, or especially for the connected graphs):
>
> 1. Is there set $A\ne \emptyset, \mathbb B^n$, such that every $\ B\subseteq \mathbb B^m\ $ which is isomorphic to $\ A\ $ is a weight-shift of $\ A?\ $
> 2. Can you describe all sets $\ A\ $ as above?
> 3. Questions related to the roots of the polynomials $\ \sum_k w_A(k)\cdot t^k\ $ (see above the part one).

Comment: @d -- References were fine all the time. I got confused by the code view, silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, I believe that only hypercubes can embed uniquely.

First note that $G$ has to be $n_2$-regular, and $n_1=1$: take any embedding, and use coordinate flips so that your favorite vertex $v$ of $G$ is embedded in $(0,0,0,...,0)$. Then $n_1=1$, and all $n_2$ vertices of weight $1$ are neighbors of $v$.

Now let $H$ be the smallest hypercube $G$ embeds uniquely into, say $|H|=2^n$. If $G$ is $n$-regular, then $G=H$. Otherwise, there is some embedding with $v=(0,...,0)$ and $(1,0,...0)\notin V(G)$. Switch the first coordinate on all vertices in $G$, giving a new embedding with minimum weight $1$. As $G$ embeds uniquely, every vertex of $G$ must have gained $1$ in weight, so all vertices had first coordinate $0$. But then $G$ embeds uniquely in the smaller hypercube, contradiction.