# Can every tromino (including those with gaps) tile the plane?

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling

I've generalized trominos to include "gaps", i.e. they are formed by removing all but $3$ squares from an $n$-omino where $n$ is finite.

[image: generalized trominos and derivative tiles demonstrating translation]

The generalized trominos pictured above can tile the plane using only translation.

[image: generalized trominos and derivative tiles demonstrating reflection]

The generalized trominos pictured above can tile the plane using only translation and reflection.

$$$$

Can all generalized trominos tile the plane employing translation, rotation, and reflection?

More interestingly, can all generalized $k$-polyhypercubes tile $k-1$ dimensional space?

Comment: Try XX X, and related, for a series that does not tile the plane without rotation.

Comment: No need to migrate - @TheMaskedAvenger answered the question. Someone can close this or I'll delete it myself.

Comment: Note that this is problem is invariant under the action of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, so if it holds for one linearly independent omino, it holds for all of them.  But classifying exactly when a non-independent omino tiles seems nontrivial.

Comment: I'll edit the question to remove the "only using translation" criterion.

Comment: Consider a translation-only tiling by a marked triomino, marked with 1 and 2 and 3, say a 3x1 tile, and mark the occurrences where 1, 2, or 3 tile occur.  This induces a pattern of numbers up to translation.  How many 1,2,3 paintings of the plane are there from translation only tessellations? (Uncountably many, I think.) Can one pass from such a painting to a decomposition in similar tiles?  Gerhard "Look At It From Underneath" Paseman, 2015.03.20

Comment: If two of the three points (=unit squares) have a common coordinate, it is easy: Suppose wlog the squares are at (0,0), (0,a) and (x,y). Fill with (a-1) horizontal translates. So we have covered [0,2a-1] x {0} and [x,x+a-1] x {y}. Add the rotation of this whole thing around the point (x/2-1/2, y/2) - and we have covered two parallel segments (i.e. strips of width 1) of equal length, which tile the whole plane. So "only" the general case with all coordinates different remains.

Comment: This only works if x≠0. So we also need to consider the special case with all 3 squares on a line. And that seems somewhat tricky!

Comment: I'll edit the question to include a picture of generalized trominos formed from straight $n$-ominos.

Comment: I don't have access to Newman, D. J., Tesselation of integers, J. Number Theory 9 (1977), 107–111, but I believe it solves the problem of tiling the integers using only translation, if the tile has a prime power number of elements (e.g., $3$). Type "tiling the integers" into Google for other work on the topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each four-celled animal tiles the plane!

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316585901050

The corresponding result for 1D three-celled "animals" holds as well.
This was a recent problem in the German Math Olympiad (Problem 531046).

Together with Wolfgang's comment this solves the original problem, since if all coordinates of the three squares are different, then one starts by horizontal translation of the "animal" by all elements of $\mathbb Z$, and then uses the 1D result.

Comment: Thanks for the information, however not everyone (including myself) is going to have access to that article. Using my original terminology, I wonder now if all generalized $k$-polyhypercubes can tile $n$ dimensional space where $n \geq k - 2$.

Comment: @IanFarrell: I placed the Coppersmith paper, "Each four-celled animal tiles the plane," at [this PDF download link](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/MathOverflow/Coppersmith4Animal.pdf).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49915/does-every-polyomino-tile-rn-for-some-n
has related information. See in particular the most recent comments.

Answer (score 0):

Imagining the plane as a checkerboard, there are two exhaustive cases for generalized trominos:

**(1)** All monominos are the same color. **(2)** Exactly two monominos are the same color.$\\\ \\\ $

Case (1) can split into two exhaustive sub-cases.

**(1.1)** Two pairs of monominos are an equal distance apart either horizontally and/or vertically.

- These generalized trominos will always tile the plane using only translation.

  1. In the direction of the equal gaps, copy translates $n$ times where $n$ is the size of the gap.
  2. Copy the result and join them together in the opposite direction of the equal gaps an infinite number of times.
  3. Copy the result and join them together in the direction of the equal gaps an infinite number of times.

  [image: Case 1.1 generalized trominos]

  Step 1 and the first six iterations of step 2 are depicted above.

**(1.2)** Three pairs of monominos are an unequal distance apart both horizontally and vertically.

- user69547's answer demonstrates these generalized trominos can tile the plane employing both translation and reflection.$\\\ \\\ $

Case (2) can split into three exhaustive sub-cases.

**(2.1)** No pairs of monominos are collinear.

- I believe these generalized trominos can tile the plane using only translation based on data.

  [image: Case 2.1 generalized trominos]

**(2.2)** One or two distinct pairs of monominos are collinear.

- These generalized trominos can always tile the plane using only translation by recursively generating infinite parallel lines at an equal distance from one another.

  1. Copy translates horizontally to the right until doing so will cause a collision.
  2. Copy the result and join the left-side of the bottom line to the right-side of the top line an infinite number of times.
  3. Copy the result and join the infinite number of line segments together horizontally an infinite number of times.
  4. Copy translates of all infinite horizontal lines vertically until no gaps remain.

  [image: Case 2.2 generalized trominos]

  Step 1 and the first iteration of step 2 are depicted above.

**(2.3)** Three distinct pairs of monominos are collinear.

- user69547's answer demonstrates these generalized trominos can tile the plane employing both translation and reflection.

Comment: Do not vandalise your post

Comment: Bob, if you wish to *delete* your own post, you can do so. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that Or someone can do that for you. But Yvette is right: mutilating a post is considered a site violation.