# Space-tiling convex prisms

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling

A *convex prism* is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ congruent to the Cartesian product of a convex polygon (the prism's base) with the interval $[0,1]$.

> **Question.** If a family of congruent convex prisms tiles space (not necessarily in a face-to-face manner), must there exist a tiling of
>   the plane with polygons congruent to the prism's base?

Comment: Is there anything special about $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^1$? Do you have counterexamples for products of $2$-dimensional base and $[0,1]^{98}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$ for example? Or proofs for a base in $\mathbb{R}^{99}$ and $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$?

Comment: @BorisBukh: No, I do not. But I think $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^1$ is an interesting case, easy to visualize. Also, a convex polygon with more than six sides cannot tile the plane.

Comment: I guess you are not assuming that the prisms are vertically oriented? (If so, of course you could just take a horizontal slice through the tiling)

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: You guess correctly. And there is a lot more that I am not assuming.

Comment: Are there non-convex counterexamples?

Comment: Yes, Noam. A $3\times4$ rectangle with a $1\times2$ rectangular hole. The prism of height 1 tiles space. The example can be cut into two congruent pieces to make a simply-connected example.
Also, if we allow the prism to be an affine image of the product, i.e., a slant prism, then convex counterexamples exist.

Comment: Right, I found something similar after asking the question,
a 4-square with a centered 2-hole.  Unfortunately I can't quite
get a counterexample from this: I can cut it into four congruent
convex pentagons, but those have a pair of parallel sides
and thus do tile the plane.   But such examples do work in
higher dimensions, as I just noted in my partial answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The following is not quite an answer, but it refutes a natural
generalization suggested in the Comments, and is too long to be
a comment itself.]

Counterexample in ${\bf R}^N \times {\bf R}$ for some $N>2$:
any lattice hexagon $H$ with angles 
$90^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $135^\circ$ 
in that order.  (That is, $H$ is obtained from a lattice rectangle by
truncating two adjacent vertices by two isosceles right lattice triangles, 
not necessarily congruent.  Alternatively, remove two congruent
lattice triangles, not necessarily isoceles, related by a 90-degree rotation.)
Then $H$ does not tile the plane, but
four copies do tile a (non-simply-connected) polyomino.  But it was
recently shown that *any* polyomino in some ${\bf Z}^n$
(which need not be simply connected, or even connected at all!) 
tiles ${\bf Z}^d$ for some $d$:

> Vytautas Gruslys, Imre Leader, and Ta Sheng Tan: Tiling with arbitrary tiles.
>   *Proc. London Math. Soc.* (2016) **112** (6): 1019-1039.
>   https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdw017 $\cong$ http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03697

(I learned about this from **Francisco Santos**'s accepted answer to 
[**Timothy Chow**'s 
 Mathoverflow question 49915](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49915), which the MO algorithm helpfully put at 
the top of its list of questions "Related" to this one.)

Comment: May I ask: What does it mean for a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to "tile" $\mathbb{R}^d$ when $d > n$?

Comment: These are polyominos, i.e. finite subsets of the tiling of ${\bf R}^n$
by ${\bf Z}^n$ translates of $[0,1]^n$.  If $d>n$, a polyomino in ${\bf Z}^n$
can be regarded as a polyomino in ${\bf Z}^d$ by taking its product with
$[0,1]^{d-n}$.  This is consistent with the prisms in **Wlodek Kuperberg**'s
question.

Comment: The question has been floating around for quite some time; this is the best answer so far.  The 3-dim. case will have to wait a bit longer.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about some way to get down to 3 dimensions but didn't find anything.  I guess one thing to ask is what's the smallest dimension to which this construction applies (the GLT paper must yield some bound but maybe in a specific case one can do significantly better).